# input type number min and max validation issue

Tags: angularjs

I have input type '`number`' and i have setup its `min` and `max` length.
I am trying to show error if user enter more than max length or number is invalid.

I have following code. I can see when i inspect element that class change to `ng-invalid ng-invalid-max` when i enter more than max allowed and tab out.

However,`no error message shows on ui.'`

**Why**?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Student</label>
    <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : studentReportForm.RollNumber.$invalid && (studentReportForm.$submitted) }">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="RollNumber" data-ng-model="studentReport.Details.RollNumber" min="0" max="10000000" />
            </div>
            <div data-ng-if="studentReportForm.RollNumber.$error.number" class="error">invalid number</div>
            <div data-ng-if="studentReportForm.RollNumber.$error.min" class="error">Min 0</div>
            <div data-ng-if="studentReportForm.RollNumber.$error.max" class="error">Max 10000000</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have got it working. The issue was incorrect form name i was referring.